# parsing and reading a floating point values in Haskell

Tags: parsing, haskell

I'm working on parsing with haskell, I want to parse a timestamp value expressed in such a way

```
946685561.618847
```

I have no problem to recognize (parse) it, but my problem is about the type of the result. I think of two situations:

1. Is there a fractional type in Haskell so that the result can be associated with the fractional value?
2. If this is not the case then how to store this value, since `Int` range from -2<sup>29</sup> to 2<sup>29</sup> - 1?

Comment: The question is if this is really a genuine fractional value or if it is better to interpret this as integral number in the appropriate unit. I.e. if your input are millisecond values, you may want to convert this to integral nano-second values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are actually multiple fractional types--there is even a whole `Fractional` class.

The most commonly used is a `Double`, which is a double-precision floating point number. You can also use `Float` which is single precision.

Another alternative is to use the `Rational` type, which lets you store a number as a ratio of two `Integer`s. (Coincidentally, `Integer` is an *unbounded* integral type. `Int` is the name for the bounded version.)

These types (`Double`, `Float` and `Rational`) are good for storing rational values. If you just want to store a large integral value, use `Integer` which is unbounded. (That is, it can store arbitrarily sized integers.)

Comment: Any of these can of course be parsed using e.g. `read "123.456" :: Double`, except `Rational` which needs syntax like `read "15432 % 125"`.

Comment: If the precision you need is (ahem) _fixed_ I'd use `Data.Fixed` rather than Rational. I'd be wary of storing Doubles unless I was interoperating with another system that stored IEEE floats. If you need fast calculation you can change Fixed to Double when you serialize and deserialize them, you will get rounding as expected.